# How to format code of react native in atom

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs, atom-editor

I am working on `react-native` app. I am using `atom` text editor for the development of `react-native` apps.

I did not find any shortcut to format `react-native` code in atom. I tried beautify package https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify but it is not working.

```
import React, {
    Component
} from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    Image,
    View,
    Text,
    Button,
    StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

class SplashScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        return ( <
            View style = {
                styles.container
            } >
            <
            Image source = {
                require('./img/talk_people.png')
            }
            style = {
                {
                    width: 300,
                    height: 300
                }
            }
            /> <
            Text style = {
                {
                    fontSize: 22,
                    textAlign: 'center',
                    marginTop: 30
                }
            } > Never forget to stay in touch with the people that matter to you. < /Text> <
            View style = {
                {
                    marginTop: 30
                }
            } > < Button title = "CONTINUE"
            color = "#FE434C" / > < /View> <
            /View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        margin: 50,
        alignItems: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column'
    }
})

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Scheduled', () => SplashScreen);
```

Comment: At the moment, atom-beautify does not support JSX. See issue [Support for JSX syntax (ReactJS)](https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify/issues/144). You may use [atom-react](https://orktes.github.io/atom-react/#indentation) package.

Comment: @Tushar any other package ?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [How to configure atom-beautify package to format with babel/jsx javascript files?](//stackoverflow.com/q/37232310)

Comment: @Tushar I read it already before asking question here!! It is not working for me. They suggested beautify which is not working. Are you OK ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I highly recommend [prettier-atom](https://atom.io/packages/prettier-atom).

[Prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier) has been getting a lot of attention lately, and for a good reason.

It's a very straight forward, opinionated JavaScript formatter with a limited set of options to suit your style. It also comes with an optional ESLint integration if you need more control.